# tensorflow einsum vs. matmul vs. tensordot

Tags: python, tensorflow, numpy-einsum

In tensorflow, the functions `tf.einsum`, `tf.matmul`, and `tf.tensordot` can all be used for the same tasks. (I realize that `tf.einsum` and `tf.tensordot` have more general definitions; I also realize that `tf.matmul` has batch functionality.) In a situation where any of the three could be used, does one function tend to be fastest? Are there other recommendation rules?

For example, suppose that `A` is a rank-2 tensor, and `b` is rank-1 tensor, and you want to compute the product `c_j = A_ij b_j`. Of the three options:

`c = tf.einsum('ij,j->i', A, b)`

`c = tf.matmul(A, tf.expand_dims(b,1))`

`c = tf.tensordot(A, b, 1)`

Is any generally preferable to the others?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Both [`tf.tensordot()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/tensordot) and [`tf.einsum()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/einsum) are syntactic sugar that wrap one or more invocations of [`tf.matmul()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/matmul) (although in some special cases `tf.einsum()` can reduce to the simpler elementwise [`tf.multiply()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/multiply)).

In the limit, I'd expect all three functions to have equivalent performance for the same computation. However, for smaller matrices, it may be more efficient to use `tf.matmul()` directly, because it would yield a simpler TensorFlow graph with fewer operations, and hence the pre-operation invocation costs will be lower.

Comment: In my example, I have to use `tf.expand_dims` on `b` before applying `tf.matmul`. In addition, using `tf.matmul` returns a rank-2 tensor rather than a rank-1 tensor; making `c` be a rank-1 tensor requires calling `tf.squeeze` after the matrix multiplication. Do the `squeeze` and `expand_dims` operations have a meaningful time cost?

Comment: They're purely metadata operations, so they have a very small constant cost, which should be dominated by the `tf.matmul()` itself.

Comment: Are you sure about this? Fundamentally, the set of possible operations with einsum is a massive superset of what is possible with matmul; which always contracts over a single axis. In numpy einsum there can be substantial performance differences