# How does tf.einsum() in tensorflow calculates gradients for matrix multiplication?

Tags: python, tensorflow

In tensorflow `tf.einsum()` can be used for matrix multiplications. For example, consider I have two tensors `A(dim=100,28,28,512)` and `B(dim=100,28,28,512)`. I am using `tf.einsum('ijkm,ijkn>imn',A,B)` to multiply matrices A and B along 2nd and 3rd dimensions. Output dimension of this multiplication will be (100, 512, 512).

How does tensorflow take care of gradient backpropagation in this case??

Answer (score 17):

I disagree with strangepoop's answer, mostly in the idea that "If you understand how backprop works in those, you can desugar to understand backprop here."

`einsum` is an elegant operation that is more fundamental than `matmul` or any other tensor operation. Understanding backpropagation in `matmul` only amounts to understanding a special case of `einsum` and presents a very limited view.

In the case of a standard `matmul` operation:

```
c = einsum("ij,jk->ik", a, b)
```

the gradient is of `c` with respect to `a` is computed in a very simple way:

```
dc/da = einsum("ik,jk->ij", np.ones_like(c), b).
```

What happened here is extremely simple: we flipped the operands and corresponding strings around. In the place of `a` we put `c` and and in the place of `ik` we put `ij`. **That's it.**

In the case of your operation:

```
C = tf.einsum('ijkm,ijkn>imn',A,B)
```

the gradient with respect to `A` is just:

```
dc/da = tf.einsum('imn,ijkn>ijkm',np.ones_like(C),B)
```

The middle operand stayed the same, we just flipped the first and last operand and string.

So what's actually going on? It's a just a natural generalization of the normal multiplication operation to arbitrary tensors.

The same way in normal multiplication

`e = a * b * c` and `de/da = de/de * b * c` (where `de/de` is just `np.ones_like(e)`),

in `einsum` it's the same thing, except `np.ones_like(e)` is now a matrix of ones, instead of just being `1` and the `*` operation is replaced with the specific `einsum` string.

If you'd like to read more about it, great! I know exactly `0` resources that talk about it in this way. If you find some, please let me know :)

Comment: +1 Great answer and very clear. Reading up on chain rule for einstein summation online is very difficult.
For practical implementation (consider your first example) if we have a loss L = f(C)
then the A update will be dL/dC . dC/dA and so instead of np.ones_like(C), we would just replace that with the incoming gradient dL/dC right?

Answer (score 1):

As noted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43104527), `tf.einsum` is just syntactic sugar for `tf.matmul` and `tf.multiply`, If you understand how backprop works in those, you can desugar to understand backprop here.