# Efficient way of multiply 3D-tensor with matrix in Tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow, matrix-multiplication, tensor

I have 2 3D-tensors A of shape (batch_size, dim1, dim2) and B of size  (batch_size, dim2, dim3). I would like to perform the following computation:

```
C = np.zeros((batch_size, dim1, dim3))
for i in range(batch_size):
    c[i] = A[i].dot(B[i])
```

I tried `C = tf.matmul(A,B)`, but got the error:

> tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Shape 
>       must be rank 2 but is rank 3 for 'MatMul' (op: 'MatMul') with input 
>       shapes: [10,100,100], [10,100]

Is there any efficient way to implement this in TensorFlow?
Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried `C=tf.matmul(A,B)`?

Comment: @mikkola yes and I get error as in the updated description

Comment: @Roger your indicates that A and B had ranks 2 and 3. Try both with rank 3

Answer (score 0):

Let's first do it with `numpy`:

```
import numpy as np
batch_size = 5
dim1 = 7
dim2 = 2
dim3 = 3

A = np.random.rand(batch_size, dim1, dim2)
B = np.random.rand(batch_size, dim2, dim3)  
C = np.zeros((batch_size, dim1, dim3)) 

for i in range(batch_size):                         
    c[i] = A[i].dot(B[i])
print(np.einsum('ikl,ilm->ikm',A,B)) - C # prints a zero array
```

Let's now do it using `tensorflow`:

```
import tensorflow as tf
a = tf.constant(A) # reusing numpy arrays
b = tf.constant(B)
op = tf.einsum('ikl,ilm->ikm',a,b)
with tf.Session() as sess:       
    print(sess.run(op) - C) # prints a zero array
```

Now according this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43104527), it looks like the performance should be rather similar with the naïve implementation.