# One line einsum functions with "interleaved" output indexing impossible to recreate using tensordot?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, numpy-einsum, tensordot

The similarities and differences between NumPy's `tensordot` and `einsum` functions are well documented and have been extensively discussed in this forum (e.g. [[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51989572/how-does-numpy-tensordot-function-works-step-by-step), [[2]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51989572/how-does-numpy-tensordot-function-works-step-by-step), [[3]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43100679/tensorflow-einsum-vs-matmul-vs-tensordot), [[4]](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.tensordot.html), [[5]](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html)). However, I've run into an instance of matrix multiplication using `einsum` that I'm finding very difficult, if not impossible, to replicate using `tensordot`: If our two arrays are,

```py
>>> A = np.array([[0, 1], [1, 0]])
>>> B = np.arange(2 ** 4).reshape((2, 2, 2, 2))
```

does there exist a one line `tensordot` equivalent to the following?

```py
>>> np.einsum("ab,ibjk->iajk", A, B)
array([[[[ 4,  5],
         [ 6,  7]],

        [[ 0,  1],
         [ 2,  3]]],


       [[[12, 13],
         [14, 15]],

        [[ 8,  9],
         [10, 11]]]])
```

From what I've found, the answer *seems* to be "no". The trouble arises in the indexing of the output dimension, `iajk`. Here, dimension `a` of array `A` appears in-between dimensions `i` and `j` of array `B`. Had the indexing of the output dimension instead been `aijk`, `np.tensordot(A, B, (1, 1))` would have worked fine. I ran a test using all possible axes to be sure,

```py
>>> output_einsum = np.einsum("ab,ibjk->iajk", A, B)
>>> axes_A = [-2, -1, 0, 1]
>>> axes_B = [-4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3]
>>> for i in axes_A:
...     for j in axes_B:
...         output_tensordot = np.tensordot(A, B, axes=(i, j))
...         if np.allclose(ouput_einsum, output_tensordot):
...             print(i,j)
...
```

and found that no combination of the allowed axes produced the desired result. Note that the dimension of `B` limits each element of the `axes` parameter to length one. Is it correct that `einsum` functions with interleaving output dimensions cannot be reproduced in one line using `tensordot`? And if is so, does there exist a multi-line work-around?

Comment: Tensordot uses reshape and transpose to reduce the problem to a simple `dot`.  `einsum` is much more general, though in this case I suspect all it's missing is a transpose of the result.

Comment: All you specify in `tensordot` is `b`, the shared sum-of-products dimension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I stress in my earlier answers, `tensordot` is an extension of `np.dot`, allowing us to specify which dimensions are used in the sum-of-products.  The `dot` default is last of A, 2nd to the last of B.

This illustrates how `dot` handles dimensions greater than 2:

```
In [158]: np.dot(np.ones((2,3,4)),np.ones((5,4,7))).shape
Out[158]: (2, 3, 5, 7)
```

The way `tensordot` puts it, the noncontracted dimensions of `B` follow those of `A`.  So taking the same arrays, but shifting the axes, produces the same thing.

```
In [162]: np.tensordot(np.ones((2,4,3)),np.ones((5,7,4)),(1,2)).shape 
Out[162]: (2, 3, 5, 7)
```

In these examples I chose distinct dimensions so the order is more obvious.

`tensordot` does not provide a way of reordering the noncontracted dimensions.     But you can easily do that yourself after.

Your example has size 2 dimensions all around.  This allows you to specify any combination of axes, but requires the use of `allclose` to test results.

```
In [146]: >>> A = np.array([[0, 1], [1, 0]])
     ...: >>> B = np.arange(2 ** 4).reshape((2, 2, 2, 2))
```

Performing the sum-of-products on the 2nd axis of both arrays:

```
In [147]: C=np.tensordot(A,B,(1,1))
In [148]: C.shape
Out[148]: (2, 2, 2, 2)
In [149]: C
Out[149]: 
array([[[[ 4,  5],
         [ 6,  7]],

        [[12, 13],
         [14, 15]]],


       [[[ 0,  1],
         [ 2,  3]],

        [[ 8,  9],
         [10, 11]]]])
```

And the `einsum` with its default result ordering ('aijk')

```
In [150]: D= np.einsum('ab,ibjk',A,B)
In [151]: np.allclose(C,D)
Out[151]: True
```

The `tensordot` is the equivalent of this `dot`:

```
In [152]: E = np.dot(A,B.reshape(2,2,4))
In [153]: E.shape
Out[153]: (2, 2, 4)
In [154]: np.allclose(C,E.reshape(2,2,2,2))
Out[154]: True
In [155]: np.allclose(E,np.einsum('ab,ibk',A,B.reshape(2,2,4)))
Out[155]: True
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Your example using the default ordering 'aijk' makes sense, but could you provide an example for the ordering 'iajk'? That was the root of my question.

Comment: `tensordot` cannot do that kind of output reordering.  It only allows you to specify the sum-of-products dimensions.  It is **NOT** as flexible as `einsum`.  `tensordot` was written before `einsum`, and IMO is largely obsolete.  `einsum` and `matmul/@` are more useful.

Comment: Ah, I understand now. Thank you.