# what is the difference between matrix multiplication methods and functions in tensorflow?

Tags: python, function, tensorflow, matrix, matrix-multiplication

What are the differences between these three ways to multiply two matrices in tensorflow? the three ways are :

1. @
2. tf.tensordot()
3. tf.matmul()

I have tested them and they give the same result. but I wanted to know if there is any underlying difference.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [tensorflow einsum vs. matmul vs. tensordot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43100679/tensorflow-einsum-vs-matmul-vs-tensordot)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us understand this with below example, I have taken two `matrix a, b` to perform these functions:

```
import tensorflow as tf

a = tf.constant([[1, 2],
                 [3, 4]])
b = tf.constant([[1, 1],
                 [1, 1]]) # or `tf.ones([2,2])`
```

`tf.matmul(a,b)` and `(a @ b)` - both performs `matrix mutiplication`

```
print(tf.matmul(a, b), "\n")   # matrix - multiplication
```

Output:

```
tf.Tensor(
[[3 3]
 [7 7]], shape=(2, 2), dtype=int32)
```

You can see the same output here as well for same matrix:

```
print(a @ b, "\n") # @ used as matrix_multiplication operator
```

Output:

```
tf.Tensor(
[[3 3]
 [7 7]], shape=(2, 2), dtype=int32)
```

`tf.tensordot()` - **Tensordot** (also known as tensor contraction) sums the product of elements from a and b over the indices specified by axes .

if we take `axes=0` (scalar, no axes):

```
print(tf.tensordot(a, b, axes=0), "\n")
#One by one each element(scalar) of first matrix multiply with all element of second matrix and keeps output in separate matrix for each element multiplication.
```

Output:

```
tf.Tensor(
[[[[1 1]
   [1 1]]

  [[2 2]
   [2 2]]]


 [[[3 3]
   [3 3]]

  [[4 4]
   [4 4]]]], shape=(2, 2, 2, 2), dtype=int32)
```

if we change `axes=1`:

```
print(tf.tensordot(a, b, axes=1), "\n")  
# performs matrix-multiplication
```

Output:

```
tf.Tensor(
[[3 3]
 [7 7]], shape=(2, 2), dtype=int32)
```

and for `axes=2`:

```
print(tf.tensordot(a, b, axes=2), "\n") 
# performs element-wise multiplication,sums the result into scalar.
```

Output:

```
tf.Tensor(10, shape=(), dtype=int32)
```

You can explore more about [tf.tensordot()](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/tensordot) and basic details on [axes](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/tensor#basics) in given links.