# Numerical discrepancy between tf.scan and matmul

Tags: tensorflow

Following the answer here: [Tensorflow - matmul of input matrix with batch data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38235555/tensorflow-matmul-of-input-matrix-with-batch-data)

I compared between the `tf.scan`-based results and the `tf.matmul`-based results. As far as I can see, the results should be identical, but I'm getting different results, consistently. I also compared with Keras' `K.dot` with the same functionality as reference.

I'll appreciate any explanation as to why that is, or what is my mistake.

Attached is the full MWE, with two results, evaluated on two separate computers (with different GPUs).

```
import tensorflow as tf
import keras.backend as K
from keras.layers import Lambda, Input
import numpy as np

na = 100
nb = 10000
mb = 10
v = Input( (1,na) )
e = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=(na,nb))

def dot_a(v):
    res = K.dot(v,e)
    return res

initer = np.zeros((1,nb),dtype=np.float32)
def dot_b(v):
    res = tf.scan(lambda a,x: tf.matmul(x, e), v, initializer=tf.constant(initer))
    return res

def dot_c(v):
    v = tf.reshape(v, [-1, na])
    h = tf.matmul(v, e)
    res = tf.reshape(h, [-1, 1, nb])
    return res

mul1 = Lambda(dot_a)(v)
mul2 = Lambda(dot_b)(v)
mul3 = Lambda(dot_c)(v)

# inputs
v0 = np.random.random((mb,1,na)).astype(np.float32)
e0 = np.random.random((na,nb)).astype(np.float32)
v0 = np.round(v0,decimals=2)
e0 = np.round(e0,decimals=2)

sess = tf.Session()
out1,out2,out3 = sess.run([mul1,mul2,mul3], feed_dict={v:v0,e:e0})
print 'norm(out, out-matmul)',np.linalg.norm(out1-out2)
print 'norm(out, out-scan)',np.linalg.norm(out1-out3)
```

Output in computer 1:

```
norm(out, out-matmul) 0.000715436
norm(out, out-scan) 0.0
```

Output in computer 2:

```
norm(out, out-matmul) 0.000511952
norm(out, out-scan) 0.0
```

Comment: With floating point math, you get different results depending on the order of operations used.  See https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/13591 for another example

Comment: Can such a non-negligible difference be caused by floating point math effects even with inputs with 2 decimal digit precision? (I'm rounding off to 2 digits in my inputs)

Comment: Not sure if that's the case here, but generally the errors due to suboptimal orders can be large. For instance, adding up numbers in a sequence left to right, you stop being able to add 1 to a floating point number at 2^24, so all such entries will get ignored