# Tensorflow Keras Tensor Multiplication with None as First Dimension

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0

I'm using TensorFlow Keras backend and I have two tensors `a`, `b` of the same shape: `(None, 4, 7)`, where `None` represents the batch dimension.

I want to do matrix multiplication, and I'm expecting a result of `(None, 4, 4)`. 
i.e. For each batch, do one matmul: `(4,7)·(7,4) = (4,4)`

Here's my code --

```
K.dot(a, K.reshape(b, (-1, 7, 4)))
```

This code gives a tensor of shape `(None, 4, None, 4)`

I'd like to know how does high-dimension matrix multiplication work? What's the right way to do this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43829731/12162096 tf.matmul is exactly what I want. Now the question is simplified --> how to use tf.matmul in Keras, is that possible?

Comment: And also, in terms of matrix multiplication, the way that `Keras backend dot method` handles None dimension seems different from tf.matmul.  
i.e. In Keras, (None, 4, 4)·(None, 4, 7) = (None, 4, None, 7).  In tf.matmul, (None, 4, 4)·(None, 4, 7) = (None, 4, 7) , which is what I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you can either use `tf.matmul` directly as part of your model and transpose `b` or explicitly wrap the operation in a `Lambda` layer:

```
import tensorflow as tf

a = tf.keras.layers.Input((4, 7))
b = tf.keras.layers.Input((4, 7))
output = tf.matmul(a, b, transpose_b=True)
model = tf.keras.Model([a, b], output)
model.summary()
```

```
Model: "model_1"
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                   Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
 input_15 (InputLayer)          [(None, 4, 7)]       0           []                               
                                                                                                  
 input_16 (InputLayer)          [(None, 4, 7)]       0           []                               
                                                                                                  
 tf.linalg.matmul_2 (TFOpLambda  (None, 4, 4)        0           ['input_15[0][0]',               
 )                                                                'input_16[0][0]']               
                                                                                                  
==================================================================================================
Total params: 0
Trainable params: 0
Non-trainable params: 0
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
```

Or

```
import tensorflow as tf

a = tf.keras.layers.Input((4, 7))
b = tf.keras.layers.Input((4, 7))
output = tf.keras.layers.Lambda(lambda x: tf.matmul(x[0], x[1], transpose_b=True))([a, b])
model = tf.keras.Model([a, b], output)
model.summary()
```